UK: What happens when the duration of a multi-leg super-off-peak train ticket is longer than the super-off-peak window?
Rail lines in the UK sell "super-off-peak tickets". These tickets are valid only for a narrow range of times.
Railways appear to be willing to sell these tickets for journeys that cannot be reasonably completed within the super-off-peak times. What happens if you cannot complete a multi-stop journey within the super-off-peak window?
For example: you'd board your super-off-peak train in Brighton, and by the time you reach Paddington station for your connection, you are no longer in the super-off-peak window.
This mostly applies three-part train-tube-train tickets that change through London, where changing between train stations within London can take an unpredictable amount of time due to e.g. congestion, closures.

Can you give an example? In general, the National Rail journey planner will only sell you tickets that can reasonably be completed, according to the extremely generous standard transfer times.

Aren't off-peak restrictions only on the departure or arrival time (depending on the direction of travel)? For instance for SWR you can arrive in London at any time after 14:00 and depart from London any time before 12:00 and 16:00 of after 19:00 (roughly). Probably a bit more complex for travel through London rather than to or from, though. A specific example may indeed help.

Your assumption that 'these tickets are valid only for a narrow range of times' is often wrong.  On LNER trains for example, with few exceptions, the entire Friday is 'super off peak'-time. If a delay causes you to miss an intended departure, for which your ticket is valid, I assume that normal passenger's rights apply and you are allowed to take the next train anyway, although out of the 'off peak' window. I second jcaron here, that it might be necessary with an example to answer your question.

@MJeffryes - Many people recommend printing out the itinerary that the journey planner gave in connection with the ticket(s) sold, to show any over zealous or mistaken ticket checkers.

Restricted Tickets will have a two-character alphanumeric restriction code: e.g. B1.  The ticket should have 'see restrictions nre.co.uk/B1' Going to that address clarifies: Applicable Days Monday to Friday Outward Travel Not valid on trains timed to depart after 04:29 and before 09:30. Return Travel Not valid on trains timed to depart after 04:29 and before 09:30. (This is just an example!)

As @MJeffryes advises, the National Rail Journey Planner will only sell you tickets that are valid on the trains you choose, and as a general note on 'Restrictions' pages says: Some tickets may require you to travel at specific times of the day, days of the week or on a specific route. Our Journey Planner takes ticket restrictions into account with the selection that you have made and will only have shown tickets that are valid for the selected trains.

The time restriction part on every ticket is different. On the retailer's website, or on National Rail Enquiries you will find a 2 alphanumeric code along with a summary of the restrictions
Let's take a Brighton to Oxford Off-Peak Return routed Any Permitted. It's code is P7, you can get its full conditions at nre.co.uk/P7
In this case it mentions a lot of specific trains and destinations that you must not take in the afternoon after a blanket 0429 to 1000 morning ban

A simpler example is B1 used on Off-Peak Day Travelcards


Applicable Days

Monday to Friday
Mondays-Fridays Outward Travel
Not valid on trains timed to depart after 04:29 and before 09:30.
Return Travel
Not valid on trains timed to depart after 04:29 and before 09:30.

Here, after 0930, you are free to use that ticket/travelcard on any train of the day

If a Super-Off-Peak is sold by a accreditated retailer, you will be able to use it on the accompanying itinerary or any other train that fill the ticket's restrictions.
And despite what staff/annoucement may tell you that Off-Peak tickets aren't valid on this train, it isn't an universal advice, trains aren't off-peak/on-peak, tickets are.
